# Using a non-static object in a static method

Tags: java, object, methods, static

Okay, I can't figure out how to work this. When the object isn't static, none of the methods or variables used work, Java just won't compile them. However, when I make the object static, the JVM returns error, throwing a popup alert and spamming the console with error messages. Here's a severely cut down version of the broken code:

```
public class Main {

public Hero hero = new Hero();

private static boolean newGuy;

public static void main(String[] args){

    areYouNew();

    if(newGuy){
        createGame();
    }else{
        loadGame();
    }
    saveGame();

}

private static void createGame() {  

}

private static void loadGame() {

    System.out.println("Ah yes, sorry. What is your name again?");

    //blah blah code here

    hero.setName();


    if(hero.getName().length() > 0 ){

    }else{
        System.out.println("Sorry? You need to type your name");
        loadGame();
    }
}

private static void areYouNew() {

    System.out.println("Are you new?");

    String newTest = sc.nextLine();
    if(newTest.toLowerCase().contains("yes")){

        newGuy = true;

    }else if(newTest.toLowerCase().contains("no")){

        newGuy = false;

    }else{
        System.out.println("Oops, it's a yes or no question.");
        areYouNew();
    }
  } 
}
```

None of the `hero.whatevers` work unless I set hero to static. Any way to fix this?
I already tried making the methods containing the references to hero non-static but then I can't use those methods in main()

Comment: You don't seem to know what you are doing. I understand you want to try it out, but I suggest going back to the tutorials, notes, books, etc. and learning what and how `static` variables and methods work.

Comment: That's the "severely cut down" version. Well thanks for being kind :-)

Comment: why would you not want hero to be static? Non static (instance) variables cannot be seen in static (class) variables.

Comment: I know I don't know what I'm doing, Sotirios. That's why I'm asking how to fix it.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "static object" (or a "non-static" one for that matter).

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a replacement for proper documentation.

Comment: Hint: Other than `main`, don't make anything `static` until you understand it better.  To reference a "non-static" (or more correctly, "instance") field or method you must have an object instance.  So do `Main me = new Main();`, then, within the main method, call/reference instance methods and fields as `me.loadGame();` and `me.newGuy = true;`.

Answer (score 0):

The `static` part of a program is code that runs without using an instance of your `Main` class. When the `main` method is called, there is no instance of the `Main` class yet.

Normally, an object instance has certain fields. In your case there is only `public Hero hero`. Static fields, like `private boolean newGuy` are not part of the instance, but more like global variables. Since there is no object instance of `Main` yet, the `hero` field can't be accessed.

It is good practice to use object-oriented programming, in Java. You should probably create a new instance of your game as quickly as possible (using `Main game = new Main()`). Then call methods on this instance (`game.createGame()`, `game.loadGame()`). Then, you don't need to make these methods static and you can access non-static fields. Also, this would allow you to have two `Main` instances at the same time, each with their own `hero` field, if such a thing would be needed at some point in your project.

You could, of course, also make the `hero` field static. It's a question of code style, I suppose.